# MySQL query is too slow, how can I improve this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, that on a table with ~300.000 rows take about 14sec to extract data.
This table will increase its size in the near future...over a million rows.
I have used the `EXISTS` clause instead of the `IN` clause, and I give an improvement.
But the query is too slow.
Can you have any solution?
Thanks in advance.

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    flow,
    COUNT(*) tot
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ff.session_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(ff.page, '#', ff.snippet_params,'$',ff.is_lead SEPARATOR '|') flow 
            FROM table_a ff
            WHERE EXISTS 
                (
                    SELECT
                        f.session_id
                    FROM table_a f
                    WHERE f.session_id = ff.session_id
                    AND f.is_lead = 1
                    GROUP BY f.user_id 
                    ORDER BY f.user_id, f.`timestamp` 
                )
            GROUP BY ff.user_id 
            ORDER BY ff.user_id, ff.`timestamp`, ff.session_id 
    )
AS flow
GROUP BY flow 
ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 10
```

This is the explain:

```
id  select_type         table       type    possible_keys       key         key_len  ref                              rows  Extra                                         
------  ------------------  ----------  ------  ------------------  ----------  -------  -----------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------
 1  PRIMARY             <derived2>  ALL     (NULL)              (NULL)      (NULL)   (NULL)                            532  Using temporary; Using filesort               
 2  DERIVED             ff          ALL     (NULL)              (NULL)      (NULL)   (NULL)                         322154  Using temporary; Using filesort               
 3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  f           ref     is_lead,session_id  session_id  767      ff.session_id       3  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra expressions in the ORDER BY don't make any sense, since the "`GROUP BY user_id`" is going to guarantee a unique value of `user_id`.

The `ORDER BY` operation are applied *after* the `GROUP BY` operation. If my intent is to get the lowest `session_id` for each `user_id`, I would use a `MIN` aggregate. In the original query, the `ORDER BY` doesn't have any influence on which `session_id` is returned.  The value returned for `session_id` is indeterminate.

(Other databases would throw an error with this query. A MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY allows the query to run, but we can get more standard behavior by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in the sql_mode.)

The `GROUP BY` within the EXISTS subquery doesn't make any sense. If row is found, then a row exists. There's no need to do a GROUP BY and aggregate the rows that are found.

And looking at it more closely, there doesn't appear to be any need to return `session_id` in the SELECT list. (Either in the `flow` view query, or in the EXISTS subquery.)

If we remove the extraneous syntax and whittle the query down to its essence, to the parts that actually matter, we are left with a query that looks like this:

```
 SELECT flow.flow  AS flow
      , COUNT(*)   AS tot
   FROM (
          SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ff.page,'#',ff.snippet_params,'$',ff.is_lead SEPARATOR '|') AS flow
            FROM table_a ff
           WHERE EXISTS
                 ( SELECT 1
                     FROM table_a f
                    WHERE f.is_lead = 1
                      AND f.session_id = ff.session_id
                 )
           GROUP BY ff.user_id
        ) flow
  GROUP BY flow.flow
  ORDER BY tot DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

The query basically says to get all rows from (the unfortunately named table) `table_a` which have a `session_id` which matches at least one row in `table_a` with the same value of `session_id` which also has `is_lead` value of 1.

And then take all of the found rows, and aggregate them based on the value in the `user_id` column.

It's very odd that there isn't an ORDER BY in the GROUP_CONCAT, and somewhat odd that there isn't a DISTINCT keyword.

It's strange for the GROUP_CONCAT aggregation to return an indeterminate ordering of the rows, and also potentially include repeated values. (Given that the outer query is going to performing another aggregation based on the value returned from that GROUP_CONCAT aggregate.)

But, I'm not sure what question this query is supposed to be answering. And I don't have any knowledge of what's unique and what's not.

We do know that the EXISTS subquery could be re-written as a JOIN operation:

```
 SELECT flow.flow  AS flow
      , COUNT(*)   AS tot
   FROM (
          SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ff.page,'#',ff.snippet_params,'$',ff.is_lead SEPARATOR '|') AS flow
            FROM ( SELECT d.session_id
                     FROM table_a d
                    WHERE d.is_lead = 1
                    GROUP BY d.session_id
                 ) e
            JOIN table_a ff
              ON ff.session_id = e.session_id
           GROUP BY ff.user_id
        ) flow
  GROUP BY flow.flow
  ORDER BY tot DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

---

We could work on making the query run faster. But before I did that, I would want to make sure that the query is returning a set that matches the specification. I need to make sure the query is actually answering the question that it's designed to answer.

I suspect that the original query isn't correct. That is, I think that if the query is returning "correct" results, it's doing so accidentally, not because it's guaranteed to. Or because there is something peculiar about the uniqueness (cardinality) of rows in the table, or due to an accidental order that the rows are being processed in.

I want to be sure that the query is guaranteed to return correct results, before I spend time tuning it, and adding indexes.

---

Q: Why isn't there an `ORDER BY` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`? e.g.

```
 GROUP_CONCAT( foo ORDER BY something)
```

Q: Is there a specific reason there isn't a DISTINCT keyword?

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT foo ORDER BY something)
```

Q: Should we be concerned with the potential for the GROUP_CONCAT to (silently) return a truncated value? (based on the setting of the `group_concat_max_length` variable?)

---

**FOLLOWUP**

For best performance of that last query in the answer above, I recommend the following index be added:

```
 ... ON table_a (session_id, is_lead, page, snippet_params)
```

or any similar index, with has `session_id` and `is_lead` as the leading columns (in that order), and also includes the `page` and `snippet_params` columns.  If an ORDER BY is added to the GROUP_CONCAT, we may want a slightly different index.

For the outer query, there's no getting around the "Using filesort" operation the derived `flow` column. (Unless you are running a more recent version of MySQL, where an index might be created. Or we're open to breaking the query into two separate operations. One query to materialize the inline view into a table, and a second query to run against that.)

Comment: I read your answer, but I need time to study it. Tomorrow I can spend some time to your answer. Ps: your query get the same results of my....but your took ~1sec.
Thanks for now, tomorrow I check and I answer to you.

Comment: The query in my answer should return an equivalent result. But I'm very suspicious of the query... especially that the value returned by GROUP_CONCAT is indeterminate. That is, MySQL could return `'2#b$y|1#a$x'` in place of `'1#a$x|2#b$y'`, either of those would satisfy the requirements. There is nothing in the query that specifies which of those values should be returned. MySQL is free to return either.

Answer (score 1):

In this subquery you are using group by but you don't have aggregation function.

For the check of EXIST  having a result for
`f.session_id` based on group by or not is the same .. you should remove the group by and the order by too

```
       WHERE EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT
                    f.session_id
                FROM table_a f
                WHERE f.session_id = ff.session_id
                AND f.is_lead = 1
                GROUP BY f.user_id 
                ORDER BY f.user_id, f.`timestamp` 
            )
```

this way

```
          WHERE EXISTS 
            (
                SELECT
                    f.session_id
                FROM table_a f
                WHERE f.session_id = ff.session_id
                AND f.is_lead = 1
            )
```

Looking at your query i think could be refactored eg:

```
SELECT flow ,  COUNT(*) tot
FROM (
            select 
            GROUP_CONCAT(ff.page, '#', ff.snippet_params,'$',ff.is_lead SEPARATOR '|') flow ,

  FROM table_a ff
  WHERE  f.is_lead = 1
            GROUP BY ff.user_id ) as new_flow

GROUP BY  flow
ORDER BY tot DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I use your suggestion, and now took ~11sec to execute! Thankyou! Unfortunately the query is slow too ;)

Comment: Maybe I have to change the DB engine? Can be an option, or not?

Comment: 3 seconds is better then nothings .. but  .. anyway   have you proper index on session_id ?

Comment: Which db engine  do you are using?

Comment: I have index on session_id, and I use MySQL 5.5

Comment: You can use a more recente version (there are some optimization and improvement ..)  but i think you shoudl refactor  yoru query firts ..  i have tried ...could be this is useful  .. i have update the answer

Comment: I try you query, its very fast, but the results are wrong ;) I try to optimize the query first, before change the DB engine...

Comment: try to refine the query ... my is a first suggestion .. because i don't know your db schema and your goal ..but i think that your query could be rewrite in a performant way ... (is not easy .. but is possible ) ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that f.session_id and f.is_lead are indexed.  It is currently doing a table scan of f for each row in the interim result against the ff reference of table_a.

Answer (score 0):

- Get rid of the count(*), IIRC MySQL can no longer cache queries if functions exist, try another approach to this.
- Get rid of the subqueries, IIRC MySQL can't cache subqueries either.

It's difficult to give an optimized version of this query (or these queries). You might wan't to change your database structure so it allows simpler queries. Perhaps some caching (redis etc.) for other values...

Comment: Hi, thanks. But this table is a "log table", I can normalize, but I have to use some table join for get the results...and I think that isn't an improvement...